# Не меняется состояние bottomSheet при возврате назад на экран

Tags: android

На главном экране приложения в onViewCreated() вызывается вот такой метод:

```
private fun showBottomSheet() {
    Log.i("ASDASD", "showBottomSheet before ${bottomSheetBehavior?.state}")
    bottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    Log.i("ASDASD", "showBottomSheet after: ${bottomSheetBehavior?.state}")
}
```

При заходе на экран bottomSheet раскрывается. Логи:

```
2022-06-15 13:52:13.256 11884-11884/com.umbrella.dragonfly.driver I/ASDASD: onViewCreated: 
2022-06-15 13:52:14.816 11884-11884/com.umbrella.dragonfly.driver I/ASDASD: showBottomSheet before 4
2022-06-15 13:52:14.816 11884-11884/com.umbrella.dragonfly.driver I/ASDASD: showBottomSheet after: 3
```

Закрываю вручную bottomSheet, перехожу на другой экран и возвращаюсь назад. Ожидаю что bottomSheet откроется снова т.к onViewCreated() вызывается и метод открытия тоже, но bottomSheet в закрытом положении.

Логи теже:

```
2022-06-15 13:52:13.256 11884-11884/com.umbrella.dragonfly.driver I/ASDASD: onViewCreated: 
2022-06-15 13:52:14.816 11884-11884/com.umbrella.dragonfly.driver I/ASDASD: showBottomSheet before 4
2022-06-15 13:52:14.816 11884-11884/com.umbrella.dragonfly.driver I/ASDASD: showBottomSheet after: 3
```

Почему так ппроисходит?

Comment: Если логи те же, могу предположить что "?" спасает ваше приложение от вылета ошибки, и, соотвественно, поэтому у вас нет никакой информации о том что происходит. **Попробуйте сделать так** `bottomSheetBehavior!!.state`, и, если приложение вылетит с ошибкой, то причина проблемы будет найдена)